# Popping to a specific viewcontroller in a navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have a come across a piece of code to pop to a specific viewcontroller in a navigation stack as below

```
for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyGroupViewController class]] ) {
        MyGroupViewController *groupViewController = (MyGroupViewController*)viewController;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The objective is to pop to MyGroupViewController. But I am not understanding this line of code.

```
MyGroupViewController *groupViewController = (MyGroupViewController*)viewController;
```

Whats exactly happening here. I don't think a new instance of MyGroupViewController is being created here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
//This for loop iterates through all the view controllers in navigation stack.   
for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    //This if condition checks whether the viewController's class is MyGroupViewController 
    // if true that means its the MyGroupViewController (which has been pushed at some point)
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyGroupViewController class]] ) {

        // Here viewController is a reference of UIViewController base class of MyGroupViewController 
        // but viewController holds MyGroupViewController  object so we can type cast it here
        MyGroupViewController *groupViewController = (MyGroupViewController*)viewController;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Also you can do like this

```
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyGroupViewController class]] ) {
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController  animated:YES];
 }
```

---

**Swift code**

```
//Itrate through all the view controllers in navigation stack
for vc in self.navigationController!.viewControllers {
  // Check if the view controller is of MyGroupViewController type
  if let myGropupVC = vc as? MyGroupViewController {
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(myGropupVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Comment: " Here viewController is a reference of UIViewController base class of MyGroupViewController 
         but viewController holds MyGroupViewController  object so we can type cast it here". This was exactly what I was looking for. So the same instance of MyGroupViewController, which is already in the navigation stack is used. Right?

Answer (score 2):

The view controllers of a navigation controller stack are being enumerated. Since these view controllers can be of any kind (but will always inherit from UIViewController), the generic UIViewController is used. However, the compiler will not know what type that view controller is, so it is being casted to a MyGroupViewController. When that happens, the compiler knows what the type of class and you can send it messages that only apply to that class.

In this case it is kind of unnecessary, as it could be simplified to this:

```
(UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MyGroupViewController class]] ) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Short answer: it changes a variable type to the type specified in the parentheses to avoid compiler warnings.

Comment: I dont have the viewcontroller instance in my current class.

Comment: @jean Paul Scott You already have created a instance of UIViewController in the fast enumeration or u can say foreach loop

Comment: `MyGroupViewController *groupViewController = (MyGroupViewController*)viewController;` I would like to know what happens in this code. Is this groupViewController the same instance which is in the navigation stack?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int m=0; m<[self.navigationController.viewControllers count]; m++) {  
            
  if([[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:m] isKindOfClass:[MyGroupViewController class]]) { 
    MyGroupViewController * groupViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers    objectAtIndex:m];  
   [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController animated:YES];   
  }   
}
```

Comment: I dont think you are answering my question.

Comment: that line will give reference to required view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) RetunToSpecificViewController{

    for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if ([controller isKindOfClass:[AnOldViewController class]]) { 
        //Do not forget to import AnOldViewController.h

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
```

On Swift

```
func RetunToSpecificViewController()
{
    let viewControllers: [UIViewController] =  self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
  self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count
        - 5], animated: true)
}
```

We have write a better tutorial on that , You can check
https://appengineer.in/2014/03/13/pop-to-specific-view-controller-in-ios/