# How can I go back to the first viewController from the third viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I entered the third viewController from the sencond viewController ,but i don't want to go back to the second viewController,I need to go back to my first viewController directly,how can I implement that.my english is poor,hope you can understand my question,thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

Currently you are in your ThirdViewController, and say your FirstViewController's class name is "FVC".

```
NSArray *allViewControllers = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) {
   if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[FVC class]]) {
       [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController  animated:YES];
   }
}
```

That should do the trick

## EDIT -

As op wanted an explanation this is how it is.

In your Navigation stack there are currently - VC1, VC2, VC3 (you are @ VC3 now).
Next when you call this method `[self.navigationController popToViewController:vc1]`, your navigation stack has VC1, as you are popping from VC3 to VC1, thus popping out all the VC's in between, thus freeing your memory

Comment: if i use this method,how can i release the second viewController.

Comment: Sorry I went out this weekend,thx for your help :),I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use navigation methods .

```
 [[self navigationController ] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

or you use this

```
popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

& pass your controller in which you want to pop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method for that

```
- (NSArray<__kindofUIViewController *> * _Nullable)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

You'll need to do something like

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Refer to the Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: but my first viewController is not my root viewController

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code -

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Or use this-

```
 NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.navigationController viewControllers]];
for (UIViewController *aViewController in allViewControllers) {
    if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[YourStoryBoardName class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11027116/3883040
.Using `isKindOfClass` you can pop to the `viewController` from your navigation stack if the `viewController` is in navigation stack.